# Shiny App not deploying: Error pushing repository: 504 Gateway Time-out Execution halted

Tags: deployment, shiny, timeout, shinydashboard, http-status-code-504

I've rerun my app several times without a problem, but am recently getting an error and can't deploy my app. It is able to run on my local desktop though so I know the

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 1414060...DONE
Deploying bundle: 2673072 for application: 1414060 ...
Waiting for task: 676723248
 building: Parsing manifest
 building: Building image: 2919203
 building: Installing system dependencies
 building: Fetching packages
 building: Installing packages
 building: Installing files
 building: Pushing image: 2919203
```

Code continues to run until I get this error message: 
`################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 676723250 error: Unhandled Exception: Error pushing repository: received unexpected HTTP status: 504 Gateway Time-out
Execution halted`

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: I am also trying to upload my app to shinyserver and receiving the same error. There is nothing wrong with my app. I also tried with toy examples given by Rstudio and they are not working either. Maybe it is a problem on their side?

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 1):

It just worked for me. I had the same issue earlier. No change to the app or connection.

https://status.rstudio.com/

> Monitoring - elevated error rating deploying applications
>   Investigating - We are observing elevated errors deploying applications to shinyapps.io. We've begun to investigate this issue and will provide further updates when we have identified the issue.
>   Dec 16, 2019 - 15:32 (PST)
>   Monitoring - We believe we identified the issue affecting the deployment of applications to shinyapps.io, and have applied a fix. Applications should be deploying properly at this time.
>   Dec 16, 2019 - 16:32 (PST)